# How to pass variables from c# to ssis package

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I am trying to build an application with ASP.NET that execute SSIS Package,so I want to pass variables from the application to this Package.
I want to know if there is some configuration missed in SSIS.

```
var a = demande_provision_creance.Année;
var t = demande_provision_creance.Trimestre;
var e = demande_provision_creance.Etat;
var i = demande_provision_creance.ID;


db.SaveChanges();


try
{


    String pkgLocation = @"C:\PROVISION_CREANCES.dtsx";

    Application app = new Application();

    Package ssisPackage = null;

    ssisPackage = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables vars = ssisPackage.Variables;

    vars["User::Annee"].Value = a;
    vars["User::trimestre"].Value = t;
    vars["User::etat"].Value = e;
    vars["User::id_demande"].Value = i;


    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = ssisPackage.Execute(null, vars, null, null, null);


    if (results == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in ssisPackage.Errors)
        {
            x += string.Concat("Package Execution results: {0}", local_DtsError.Description.ToString());
        }
    }

}
catch (DtsException ex)
{
    // Exception = ex.Message;
}
return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you don't need to provide the variables scope beside of the variables name:

```
vars["Annee"].Value = a;
vars["trimestre"].Value = t;
vars["etat"].Value = e;
vars["id_demande"].Value = i;
```

Providing the scope is used within a script component or script task, but not when working with packages programatically.

- [Working with Variables Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/working-with-variables-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)